# pruebas unitarias en Angular de navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition cuando da error

Tags: angular, unittest, karma-jasmine

Tengo un método de un servicio en angular que estoy testeando y me gustaría hacer la prueba unitaria cuando de error, ya que al momento de hacer el coverage me indica que me hace falta hacerle un test en la parte de error

```
location(): Promise<Coord> {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      ({ coords }) => {
        res({ lat: coords.latitude, lon: coords.longitude });
      },
      (err) => {
        rej(err);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

logre hacer la prueba cuando da correcta mostrando las coordenadas, pero no cuando da error acá la prueba unitaria correcta

```
it('should return coords', async () => {
  const mockData = {
    coords: {
      accuracy: 0,
      altitude: 0,
      altitudeAccuracy: 0,
      heading: 0,
      latitude: 1000,
      longitude: 2000,
      speed: 0,
    },
    timestamp: 0,
  };
  spyOn(navigator.geolocation, 'getCurrentPosition').and.callFake(
    (successFn) => {
      successFn(mockData);
    }
  );


  const res = await service.locationPermissions();
  expect(res).toEqual({
    lat: mockData.coords.latitude,
    lon: mockData.coords.longitude,
  });
});
```

¿alguna idea de como puedo hacer la prueba unitaria cuando el Promise me dé reject?